# WordPress How to reorder Page/Post Settings

Tags: hooks, block-editor

I am trying to move Yoast Seo to the bottom of my Post/Page settings sidebar. I am not sure how to hook into those so I can change the order.
Order I need

1. Status & Visibility
2. Permalinks
3. Discussion
4. Page Attributes
5. Yoast Seo

Currently it looks like

1. Status & Visibility
2. Yoast Seo
3. Permalinks
4. Discussion
5. Page Attributes

Comment: those panels appear in the order they're registered, no ordering functionality has been implemented yet

Comment: @TomJNowell Could I unregister Yoast SEO and reregister it to appear at the bottom? If so is that as simple as Deactivating and then Activating the plugin?

Comment: it's the time it's registered in code in JS in the browser, completely unrelated to plugin activation, this is not a trivial task, and may not be possible without making modifications to Yoast itself, if it's possible at all